# Notepad++ how to remove duplicated words with different numbers

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file like this with over 70,000 lines:

```
discovered_items[0]: 434203938999435346
discovered_items[1]: 434477435732567237
discovered_items[2]: 434477435749337074
```

I want to remove all the lines that say `discovered_items[0]:` that goes from 0 to 70,000 and just leave the numbers that go after that to end up with something like this:

```
434203938999435346
434477435732567237
434477435749337074
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you already have tried something please post it here, otherwise this question might get closed.

Answer (score 2):

- Press Ctrl+H to open the Find and Replace window
- Find what: `discovered_items\[\d+\]:\s(\d+)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Click on Replace All